# How to produce an Icon for the Notification.Action.Builder(...) constructor parameter?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Notification.Action.Builder() constructor takes an Icon as input parameter, but I don't know how to produce an Icon? There seems to be no info on that. Old Builder constructor which takes a drawable Int is now deprecated.

```
public Builder(Icon icon, CharSequence title, PendingIntent intent) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Icon` class is an encapsulation class for different kinds of methods to fetch an icon (e.g. bitmap, from file,...)

all (static) methods are listed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon)

If you want to access an icon by its drawable int, you can do the following:

```java
Icon icon = Icon.createWithResource(context,R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE_REFERENCE);
```